# How can I overwrite a default table model?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

In Java NetBeans, I want to show in a default table model the contents of student table.

`SELECT * FROM students`

I made this. But when I want to show the content of `SELECT * FROM grades` this shows me in the same default table model.

So I want to delete entire table and make another.

---

When I write `SELECT * FROM students` it shows in the table, but when I write `SELECT * FROM grades` 
I want to overwrite this table and show only the content from `SELECT * FROM grades`.

Answer (score 0):

if i get you right, then try this:

after the first select (select * from students) clear the default model like this:

```
if (myTableModel.getRowCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = myTableModel.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        myTableModel.removeRow(i);
    }
}
```

and then fill it with the second select

Comment: Thanks! 
I tried but doesn`t work. 

But I found this and work:

model.setRowCount(0);
model.setColumnCount(0);